# pass aoData Parameters from another function in jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I calling data Table function from different places with different number of parameters .So i need to pass this parameters accordingly in data table.How can I achieve this.I am using data Table version  1.9.4

This is my snippet

```
    function TestList(dataStr){
        oTable = $('#editable_1').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bLengthChange": true,
        ............................
        ............................
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
                aoData.push(dataStr),
                oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
```

this function I am calling from another function

```
 TestList(dataStr);
```

and the dataStr I defined like this

```
    var dataStr = [];
                dataStr[0]= {'name':'test1', 'value':222};
                dataStr[1]= {'name':'test2', 'value':333};
                dataStr[2]= {'name':'test3', 'value':444}

;
```

But this doesn't work.Please Can anyone help to find this solutions.Any help an guidance will appreciated

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @marpsmith.thanks you help..no error but the parameters am not getting in controller.

Comment: I'm very confused; do you mean the `dataStr` variable is not visible in the `"fnServerData": function...` function?